# How to get a SQL dump for development in Shopware 6?

Tags: database, shopware6

We are developing a customers shop and want to develop locally, but without all the user / order data.

How can we achieve this?

The question has those points:

1. How to create such dumps?
2. How to import them?
3. How to manage storage / make them easily accessible for developers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [smile SA gdpr dump](https://github.com/Smile-SA/gdpr-dump) to create a anonmyized dump which is fine for development.

This can be either stored in GIT or downloaded from the production server or you might setup another server to store those dumps.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a nice script from kellerkinder especially for shopware 6 https://github.com/kellerkinderDE/shopware6-database-dump

To import just use `mysql --force -u -p my-database < dump.sql`